# How to make two words come in single line

Tags: html, css, angular

```html
<div>Mandatory Documents</div>
<div>
  <button type="text" (click)="delete()" pButton icon="pi pi-times" label="Delete">
</button>
</div>
```

I have two div tags. The word **Mandatory Documents** is coming in two lines. I need the whole word to come in only one line and the **Delete** button beside to it

What CSS should I apply?

[image]

Comment: What HTML dialect allows attributes like "`(click)`" to be written in round brackets?

Comment: its just angular

Comment: can you please post any remainder html / css that is surrounding this part of the code?  it must be the size of the outside container(s).

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use "display: inline-block"  by default div elements are block.  or you could also span i guess which are inline by default.   I dont know why you say don't break the two words?  anyway you could add `&nbsp;` between the words so it wouldnt break

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">Mandatory&nbsp;Documents</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <button type="text" (click)="delete()" pButton icon="pi pi-times" label="Delete">test</button>
</div>
```

I just don't understand why it would split up the words?  can you provide a screen shot if it doesnt work just to show the full layout?

Comment: Added screenshot in question

Comment: i tested it in stackblitz.  please provide all of your code or make a stackblitz

Comment: ok so the remaining problem is the word break. most probably its in a too small container.  try with min-width or something like it.  you can try different options easily in chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-breakable space between your words: `&nbsp;`

To keep the two `div` on the same line, use `display: flex` on their parent with `flex-direction: row`. Here is an example with a parent container which is too small yet the children are correctly placed on the same row.

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.group > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div>Mandatory&nbsp;Documents</div>
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="group">
  <div>Mandatory Documents</div>
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use &nbsp the words Mandatory Documents are coming in one line but the Delete button is getting overlapped with the words

Comment: Then your container may be too small, increase its size. See my last example with display: flex